# Odd behaviour Using num2str in Octave

Tags: format, octave, precision

Having issue with the `num2str` function in Octave.

```
string = num2str(8.395,3);
```

String returns "8.39"
whereas,

```
string = num2str(1.395,3);
```

returns "1.4".

How can it be possible?
How can I get a consistent number of decimals?

Answer (score 2):

[IEEE floating point rounds to the nearest even number when exactly half-way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even). So the first case it rounds down towards 8, and in the second one up towards 2.

I think this will always show 3 digits ([ref](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.1/Output-Conversion-Syntax.html)):

```
num2str(x,'%4.2f')
```

Comment: Thanks! But It is not useful for me since I need to have 3 significant figures in each number I got. That's why I needed the other way.

Comment: @Fernando: what do you mean? This returns "8.39" and "1.40", that is three digits in both numbers. If you need something else, please edit your question to clearly show exactly what it is that you expect as output.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be "why is 8.395 rounded "down", whereas 1.395 is rounded "up". Is that a bug?

Yes and no. This is an inherent limitation of floating-point arithmetic. Effectively, neither of those two numbers can be expressed exactly in floating-point format, therefore their nearest approximation is used. It just so happens that the nearest approximation for 8.395 is just "under" that value, whereas for 1.395 is just "above" it. Hence octave rounds the first "downwards", and the latter "upwards". You can confirm this if you print more significant digits for each:

```
sprintf("%.20f", 8.395)   % ans = 8.39499999999999957367
sprintf("%.20f", 1.395)   % ans = 1.39500000000000001776
```

So, as far as the "actual numbers in memory" are concerned, octave is doing the right thing.

If you do not care about 'actual precision' and you just want to see 'visually-desired precision', then you can create a simple function that uses "round" (i.e. to the nearest integer) under the hood. E.g.

```
ndigits   = @(x)    10 ^ floor( log10( x ) );
sigdigits = @(x, s) round( x / ndigits(x) * 10^s ) / 10^s * ndigits(x);

sigdigits(8.395, 2)   % ans =  8.4000
sigdigits(1.395, 2)   % ans =  1.4000
```